# HTML/CSS Why does my icon not load instantly & how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

a.nounderline{
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #1478a0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;

}

a.nounderline span{
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.container{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;

}

.floating-menu{
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Changa One', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  height: 42%;
}

   .icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

a.new_paragraph span {
  line-height: 0em;
  display: block;
}

.main-menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;

}.main-menu li a{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 36px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;

}

.main-menu li a:hover{
  color: #1478a0;
}

.menu-bg{
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:55px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Access Denied">
    <meta name="author" content="AccessDenied">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Social Media">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AccessDenied</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alef:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">ACCESS<span>DENIED</span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <sidebar>
      <nav class="floating-menu">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" class="absoluteCenterWrapper">
                  <img class="icon" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" class="absoluteCenter">
                  <div>LOGIN</div>
              </a>

              </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >REGISTER</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="new_paragraph" >GET<span>PREMIUM</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-bg"></div>

      </nav>
    </sidebar>
    <footer>
    </footer>

  </body>





</html>
```

Hello community,
I added an icon for my navbar for the login, but when I load the website, the icon doesnt load instantly.  How can I change it? I heard that it's better to use links for inserting pictures or icons to your website because it loads faster than when having a seperate picture in your project file as .png or .jpg.
It really sucks that its slowly loading, usually on other websites its instant.
Thanks!

Comment: The icon loads instantly for me. But you're not hosting it yourself, which is asking for trouble.

Comment: No, look again carefully. It is not loading instantly.

Comment: It does load instantly on my computer, probably because my browser is preloading it or it already has it in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is its a massive image scaled down to icon size with your CSS and is probably being grabbed from a slow server. Here, all I did was reupload that icon to imgur and made it smaller. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/46vKC.png  And look how your code runs now:

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

a.nounderline{
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #1478a0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;

}

a.nounderline span{
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.container{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;

}

.floating-menu{
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Changa One', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  height: 42%;
}

   .icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

a.new_paragraph span {
  line-height: 0em;
  display: block;
}

.main-menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;

}.main-menu li a{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 36px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;

}

.main-menu li a:hover{
  color: #1478a0;
}

.menu-bg{
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:55px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Access Denied">
    <meta name="author" content="AccessDenied">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Social Media">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AccessDenied</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alef:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">ACCESS<span>DENIED</span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <sidebar>
      <nav class="floating-menu">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" class="absoluteCenterWrapper">
                  <img class="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/46vKC.png" class="absoluteCenter">
                  <div>LOGIN</div>
              </a>

              </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >REGISTER</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="new_paragraph" >GET<span>PREMIUM</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-bg"></div>

      </nav>
    </sidebar>
    <footer>
    </footer>

  </body>





</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your server and cdn config BUT as written,

It loads pretty darn fast (there is no loading animation or logic waits just load order and parallelization issues). If you want it to load faster you can offset your font links, each of those is going to take up a DNS lookup and load BEFORE your image. You can either prefetch, async, or defer these. If you are going to add a css reference do the same. Javscript do the same. Internal CSS style tag move it to bottom of body. You can also move fonts, js, css to local file so it doesn't use DNS to do lookups. Additionally, your CDN is serving on http1.1 ideally you want http2 for more parallelization. Finally, you have no caching on the image on web, this should be set in your CDN for that image or image file types in general. That means you'd only ever need to download it one time.

Much more server specific is cache control for your other assets. If you make people download js, css, fonts everytime they load your site then its always gonna suck up more time than if you cache it.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow on my machine too - over 600 ms - and it does not get cached.

If you don't have better options as far as a sever to host it on, you could consider embedding it directly into your HTML. Here's a site that will convert your existing URL into a base 64 img tag, that you just include directly in your page and there's no additional load needed:

https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/png

Answer (score 0):

If you link to an external asset, the loading time can only be as fast as the speed and throughput external source's servers permit for the nature and size of the asset. In general, images are always going to load more slowly than text, html and your CSS styles. There are ways to mitigate against this using optimisations in front- and back-end code, but there are also low-hanging fruits if you wish to keep your project relatively simple.  It's worth noting that all of the icons on the homepage of onlinewebfonts.com took a little while to load, and it's probable that they aren't prioritising performance as a free and honestly rather old-school looking service.

I have a few suggestions that may help you out.

1. Firstly, the gold-standard for external icons (many of which are completely free) is [fontawesome.com](https://fontawesome.com/). They provide copy-and-paste html for hundreds of modern, performant icons plus guides for hosting, CSS styling and accessibility.
2. Secondly, consider the format and resolution of the content you wish to include. The icon you have chosen is a medium-to-large PNG. Considering the rendered size of the icon, this could be overkill and would naturally increase the load time. As Dai mentioned, self-hosting gives you more control over loading and content sizing; you could create a smaller, optimised version of the file and host it yourself with your html and css files.
3. Finally, depending on your project goals, you could consider a more advanced solution and create your own icon using the [SVG html element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg). SVGs give you a tonne of creative flexibility in an efficient, embedded format which doesn't load via a separate HTTP request but simultaneously with your html. (Worth noting here that this does mean these icons cannot be cached or pre-loaded.) There are loads of free-to-use SVG code templates if you search for them, or you can attempt to create a unique one of your own design using the numerous permitted shape and fragment elements, or in a vector graphics program like Adobe Illustrator. Lots more on SVGs at [csstricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Hope this helps!